# Angular component html element undefined when called in function from service

Tags: angular

I created this error service according to this tutorial: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/expecting-the-unexpected-best-practices-for-error-handling-in-angular-21c3662ef9e4

And whenever there's an error it display a snackbar. He uses the one from Angular Material, I wanted to make my own.

I tried to hide/show it with ngIf, ngClass, eventually by calling the HTMLElement and that led me to discover that whenever the function is called from the service the div inside the component is undefined. And only when called from the service, because when calling the function on the component itself it works as expected.

The component is always there, it's in the main component, but the div inside just gets shown.

```
import { Component, ElementRef, Injectable, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
   selector: "app-snackbar",
   templateUrl: "./snackbar.component.html",
   styleUrls: ["./snackbar.component.scss"]
})
@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class SnackbarComponent {

   @ViewChild("snackbar", { static: false }) snackbar: ElementRef < HTMLDivElement > = {} as ElementRef;

   message = "";

   ngAfterViewInit(): void {
      console.log("afterViewInit");
      console.log(this.snackbar);
   }

   open(message: string): void {
      console.log("open");
      this.message = message;
      console.log(this.snackbar) // => here it's undefined
      //this.snackbar.nativeElement.classList.remove("hidden");
    }

    close(): void {
       this.message = "";
       console.log(this.snackbar)
       this.snackbar.nativeElement.classList.add("hidden");
    }

 }
```

It's clear that it's missing something, does anyone know what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [official Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services):

> A component should use services for tasks that don't involve the view
> or application logic. Services are good for tasks such as fetching
> data from the server, validating user input, or logging directly to
> the console. By defining such processing tasks in an injectable
> service class, you make those tasks available to any component. You
> can also make your application more adaptable by injecting different
> providers of the same kind of service, as appropriate in different
> circumstances.

Which means that you should not have a @ViewChild() or anything that directly access the DOM in your Service. Angular does not enforce these rules strictly, hence the NG build not pre-empting you.
This best practice is common across many programming languages: separation of concerns principle.

What you could do instead is to outsource the view-controlling part to an Angular component.

Such a component could be as follows:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SnackbarService } from './snackbar.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-snackbar',
  templateUrl: './snackbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./snackbar.component.scss']
})
export class SnackbarComponent {
  message: string = '';
  show: boolean = false;

  constructor(private snackbarService: SnackbarService) {
    this.snackbarService.snackbarState$.subscribe(state => {
      this.message = state.message;
      this.show = state.show;
    });
  }
}
```

and your Service could be refactored as:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class SnackbarService {
    private _snackbarState = new BehaviorSubject<{message: string, show: boolean}>({message: '', show: false});
    snackbarState$ = this._snackbarState.asObservable();

    showSnackbar(message: string): void {
        this._snackbarState.next({message: message, show: true});
    }

    hideSnackbar(): void {
        this._snackbarState.next({message: '', show: false});
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah, that wasn't the original plan anyway, just a last resort, but thanks it works now! Weirdly enough I do have to move my mouse for it to show up, but that could be because I'm doing some video encoding and my system's a bit sluggish at the moment. I'll have to test it again later. At least it does show up now. Thank you very much!